# Type.GetFields returns empty array

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I am trying to get public fields dynamically but it keeps returning an empty list.  I load a usercontrol successfully but it is of type UserControl which means I use .BaseType to get the real type.  But when I call .GetFields() it returns an empty FieldInfo array.

```
usercontrolPath = "/usercontrols/HelloWorldTestUC.ascx"
Page pageHolder = new Page();
UserControl usercontrol = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl("~/" + usercontrolPath);
Type type = usercontrol.GetType().BaseType;

FieldInfo[] infos = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public);

//i will do something here
control.Controls.Add(usercontrol);
```

Here is the UserControl code:

```
public partial class HelloWorldTestUC : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public int Number = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            txtMessage.Text = Message.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why it would return an empty array?  It should return 'Number' at the very least.

Comment: whay do you need .BaseType ?

Comment: UserControl.BaseType will give me the actual type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your BindingFlags are incomplete. You probably want `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance` to get public, instance fields.

Comment: So when instance isnt passed, it just returns back static fields?

Comment: No, from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfields?view=netframework-4.8) :  For the GetFields(BindingFlags) overload to successfully retrieve property information, the bindingAttr argument must include at least one of BindingFlags.Instance and BindingFlags.Static, along with at least one of BindingFlags.NonPublic and BindingFlags.Public.